# PHP Logic Issue on Selector

Tags: php, sql

I have an event booking system that shows available slots for a testing system and I'm really stuck on some logic.

`event_information` (A) stores the details about the event

`event_machine_time` (B) stores the testing laptop event times as the machine is only allowed to be used at certain times everyday

```
*********************************************
* id * machine_name * start_time * end_time *
*********************************************
* 1  * LPN832       * 09:30:00   * 11:00:00 *
* 2  * LPN832       * 11:30:00   * 13:00:00 *
* 3  * LPN832       * 13:30:00   * 15:00:00 *
* 4  * MHY348       * 09:30:00   * 11:00:00 *
* 5  * MHY348       * 11:30:00   * 13:00:00 *
* 6  * MHY348       * 13:30:00   * 15:00:00 *
*********************************************
```

`event_booking` (C) stores the booking detail including if the person has declined the event through `c_confirmed` and if the person has been deleted through `live`

```
***************************************************************************
* id * information_id * candidate_id * machine_name_id * live * confirmed *
* 3  * 2666           * 356          * 1               * 1    * 2         *
* 4  * 2666           * 456          * 1               * 1    * 0         *
***************************************************************************

So my statuses for confirmed are:
0 - Not confirmed
1 - Confirmed
2 - Declined

My statuses for live are:
1 - Live
0 - Deleted
```

And here is my code:

```
$Machine_Query = "SELECT *,
        B.id AS m_id,
        C.id AS c_id,
        C.confirmed AS c_confirmed,
        C.live AS c_live
        FROM event_information A
        INNER JOIN event_machine_time B on (1=1)
        LEFT JOIN event_booking C on (B.id = C.machine_time_id and A.id = C.information_id )
        WHERE A.id = '$Event_Data_ID'
        ORDER BY B.machine_name ASC, B.start_time ASC";
        $Machine = $dbconn->query($Machine_Query);
```

And for my dropdown selector I use the following:

```
<?php foreach ($Machine->fetchAll() as $Machine_Row) { 
                //if($Machine_Row["confirmed"] == 2) { } else {
                ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $Machine_Row["m_id"]; ?>" <?php if($Machine_Row["c_id"] != NULL && $Machine_Row["c_confirmed"] != "2" && $Machine_Row["c_live"] != "0") { echo "disabled"; } ?>><?php echo $Machine_Row["machine_name"]." - ".date("g:ia", strtotime($Machine_Row["start_time"])); ?><?php if($Machine_Row["c_id"] != NULL && $Machine_Row["c_confirmed"] != "2" && $Machine_Row["c_live"] != "0") { echo " - Booked"; } ?></option>
        <?php } //} ?>
```

Heres the output using the example above where one user is waiting to confirm (so it shows booked) and the other has declined - See how it then shows an extra slot and the same applies if I change the live status:

[image]

Now you can see I've added a dirty fix that I've commented that does solve the problem, but it really should exist in the SQL as I can't build a validity checker properly without trying to isolate at the SQL.

This is driving me mad and it's most likely the angle I'm looking at it from, so  fresh eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add this line `AND B.confirmed <> 2` after `WHERE A.id = '$Event_Data_ID'`;

Comment: What is your SGBD ?

Comment: I'm really surprised this question gets upvotes.  I can't figure out what the *question* is.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a boolean to know when to disable the option (here named `booked`):

```
(c.id IS NOT NULL AND C.confirmed != 2 AND C.live != 0) AS booked
```

I edited a bit your PDO query:

```
$Machine = $dbconn->prepare(
    'SELECT
        *,
        B.id AS m_id,
        C.id AS c_id,
        C.confirmed AS c_confirmed,
        C.live AS c_live,
        (c.id IS NOT NULL AND C.confirmed != 2 AND C.live != 0) AS booked   
    FROM event_information A
        INNER JOIN event_machine_time B
            ON (1 = 1)
        LEFT JOIN event_booking C
            ON (B.id = C.machine_time_id AND A.id = C.information_id)
    WHERE A.id = :event_data_id
    ORDER BY B.machine_name ASC, B.start_time ASC'
);

$dbconn->execute([ 'event_data_id' => $Event_Data_ID ]);
```

This will be much shorter to output in the HTML (using a ternary operator will look better in a single line):

```
<?php
foreach ($Machine->fetchAll() as $Machine_Row) { 
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $Machine_Row["m_id"]; ?>" <?php echo $Machine_Row['booked'] ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>>
        <?php echo $Machine_Row["machine_name"] . " - " . date("g:ia", strtotime($Machine_Row["start_time"])) . ($Machine_Row['booked'] ? ' - Booked' : ''); ?>
    </option>
    <?php
}
?>
```